# How can I find the intersection of this problem?

Tags: probability

For this question I was trying a Venn diagram with center $x$ but I can't seem to figure out what this is by working backwards. Here's the problem:

There are 162 math majors at the school. Of these, 91 are female, 34 are seniors, 44 are seeking secondary certification, 18 are females and seniors, 25 are females seeking secondary certification, and 12 are seniors seeking secondary certification. You are given that there are 5 times as many math majors who are in NONE of these 3 groups as there are math majors who are in ALL 3 of these groups. Find the number of math majors who are female seniors seeking secondary certification.

So far I've found the number of male non-seniors and the number of males not seeking secondary certification but I can't figure out how to get all 3 of these to find what $x$ is.

Comment: Witn $F$ - female, $S$ - seniors, $C$ - seeking secondary certification, one get: $$162-|F\cup S\cup C|=5x.$$ Use inclusion-exclusion principle to write some expression for $|F\cup S\cup C|$ and put it backward into the equation above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

F - Females; S - Seniors; C - Certification
There are 162 - 91 = 71 males
There are 71 - (S + D + C) math majors who are in NONE of the 3 groups.
Which gives us 71 - (S + D + C) = 5X
You also know:

F + A + B + X = 91  (Females)
S + A + D + X = 34  (Seniors)
C + B + D + X = 44  (Certification)
A + X = 18             (Females and Seniors)
D + X = 12             (Seniors and Certification)
B + X = 25             (Females and Certification)

[image]

Comment: How do you find S, C, and F?

Comment: I've edited my answer to provide more information.